# MySQL num_rows Returning False Positive

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query below:

```
// They have a token and estimate id
if (isset($_GET['estimate_token']) && isset($_GET['estimate_id']))
{
    if ($select = $db -> prepare("SELECT estimate_id FROM estimates WHERE estimate_token =?"))
    {
        $select -> bind_param('s', $_GET['estimate_token']);
        $select -> execute();
        $select -> store_result();
        $select -> bind_result($estimate_id);
        $select -> fetch();
        if ($select -> num_rows == '0')
        {
            header ("Location: ./login.php");
        }else{
        }
        $select -> close();
    }
}
```

Customers are given a link via email with the token and an estimate id from the database. When they click the link it brings them to the correct estimate. The problem I am having is that if the customers manually replaces the estimate_id or estimate_token with any number in the url it still keeps you on the website where it should kicking you to the login.php. This is bad because it allows customers to view other estimates in the system.

I think the problem lies in the `$select -> num_rows` throwing a false positive.

Comment: Just validate that they match. `SELECT ... WHERE estimate_token=? AND  estimate_id=?`. If the number of rows returned is zero, they didn't match, so send them away. (You should also use `exit;` after your `header();` call)

Comment: Don't put numbers in quotes (this isn't your problem though). Just 0 is better although that too is unnecessary - just `if (!$select -> num_rows)` works too.

Comment: @Luke Actually, `"0" == 0` is true in PHP (the string zero versus the number zero), because the comparison isn't *strict* (`===`).

Comment: Yep of course, but it's slower than it needs to be.

Comment: @Qirel i.e. internally it triggers the much slower comparators; it casts the string to a suitable number. It's infamously unreliable too as it doesn't commute. Adding quotes is more typing and it runs slower, so it's never necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You logic is invalid - you **must** find a record where both `token` and `id` equals to `$_GET` values, so you need to use query like:

```
$SELECT estimate_id FROM estimates WHERE estimate_token =? AND estimate_id = ?
```

This will select only one certain record.

Full code is something like:

```
if ($select = $db -> prepare("SELECT estimate_id FROM estimates WHERE estimate_token = ? and estimate_id = ?"))
{
    // supposing id is `int`
    $select -> bind_param('si', $_GET['estimate_token'], $_GET['estimate_id']);
    $select -> execute();
    $select -> store_result();
    // if you need to know just if row exists
    // there's no need for this two lines
    //$select -> bind_result($estimate_id);
    //$select -> fetch();
    if ($select -> num_rows == 0)
    {
        header ("Location: ./login.php");
    } else {
    }
    $select -> close();
}
```

Comment: This is close but we are still not getting kicked if we type in a valid estimate id. So if my estimate id is 1 and there is an estimate with id 2 all I have to do is replace `estimate_id=1` with `estimate_id=2` in the url and I can view someone else's estimate. I need to make it so it only gets a result from the database if both fields match.

Comment: Doesn't `WHERE estimate_token = ? and estimate_id = ?` require __both__ fields match?

Comment: I would think so but It's getting a estimate_id based on our select statement without a matching estimate_token.

Comment: Caching strikes again! Emptied my cache and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. I remove my comments so as not to make answer more complicate for other people)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you kick them out immediately if they don't have a token? I think that might be the problem. Or , with the way you've written it, you don't have an ELSE for what happens if they don't have a token and estimate ID. Your only ELSE statement is inside your DB select code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like much more sane logic, which will ensure they're thrown to login when they submit no, or blank tokens/IDs. It will also cover you if you needed to do any further validation as you just have 1 bool to set if you need to throw them out.

Since you're not using the result from the database either, changing it to a database-side count may be slightly quicker.

```
$needsLogin = true;

if (!empty($_GET['estimate_token']) && !empty($_GET['estimate_id']))
{
    $select = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM estimates WHERE estimate_token = ? AND estimate_id = ?');
    $select->bind_params('si', $_GET['estimate_token'], $_GET['estimate_id']);
    $select->execute();
    $select->bind_result($cnt);
    $select->fetch();
    if ($cnt > 0) {
        $needsLogin = false;
    }
    $select->close();
}

if ($needsLogin) {
    header('Location: ./login.php');
    die();
}
```

PS. PDO will make your DB code nicer to deal with:

```
$select = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM estimates WHERE estimate_token = ? AND estimate_id = ?');
$select->execute(array($_GET['estimate_token'], $_GET['estimate_id']));
$cnt = $select->fetchColumn();
if ($cnt > 0) {
    $needsLogin = false;
}
```